# Como identificar o elemento exato que contem uma palavra expecifica

Tags: javascript, html

**Como exibir apenas o elemento no qual a palavra pesquisada se encontra?**

No exemplo abaixo ele pesquisa nos `filhos` do `container` caso o conteúdo pesquisado esteja presente no elemento o move para a `saida`.

Mas nesse caso pelo elemento "pai" ter a palavra pesquisada, ele será movido inteiro para a `saida`, e não o elemento no qual a palavra se encontra.

```js
function pesquisar(){
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  let saida = document.getElementById("saida");
  let input = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
  let filhos = container.children;
  for(let i = 0; i < filhos.length; i++){
    if(filhos[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input) || filhos[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
      saida.appendChild(filhos[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"><button onclick="pesquisar()">Pesquisar</button>
<h3>Entrada</h3>
<div id="container">
  <div class="pai">
    <div class="pai">
      <div class="filho">Conteudo</div>
      <div class="filho">Pesquisado</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Saida</h3>
<div id="saida"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `.children` só retorna filhos diretos (não netos, bisnetos etc.). O seu código está buscando dentro do único filho direto de `#container` se existe o texto buscado. Tanto o `innerText` quanto o `includes` busca todo o texto dentro do elemento, não importa onde ele esteja (se em filhos, netos, bisnetos etc.), por isso ele irá retornar o primeiro `<div class="pai">` (repito: único filho direto da div `#container` que o `.children` retorna).

O que você pode fazer é usar o `.querySelectorAll("*");` na div `#container`. Esse método irá retornar todos os elementos e não apenas os filhos diretos de `#container`. Daí você faz um segundo laço `for` percorrendo os nós com `.childNodes` verificando se é um nó de texto (`nodeType == 3`) e se esse texto possui o termo buscado. Se encontrar, você pega o elemento pai `.parentNode` desse nó e faz o append:

**Obs.:** use `textContent` em vez de `innerText`, já que um nó de texto não é um elemento de conteúdo interno.

```js
function pesquisar(){
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  let saida = document.getElementById("saida");
  let input = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
  let filhos = container.querySelectorAll("*");
  for(let i = 0; i < filhos.length; i++){
     let nodes = filhos[i].childNodes;
     for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
       if(nodes[i].nodeType == 3 && (nodes[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input) || nodes[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1)){
         saida.appendChild(nodes[i].parentNode);
       }
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Conteudo" id="input"><button onclick="pesquisar()">Pesquisar</button>
<h3>Entrada</h3>
<div id="container">
  <div class="pai">
    <div class="pai">
      <div class="filho">Conteudo</div>
      <div class="filho">Pesquisado</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Saida</h3>
<div id="saida"></div>
```